# CRX_ZREO_SIGNTURE_LENGTH failure in .crx file

Tags: php

I have found this post [Create Google Chrome Crx file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013263/create-google-chrome-crx-file-with-php) 
to create a .crx file vith my ZIP archive.
but when I try to run it I got a length of $signtrue = 0
and I didn't figure out why...my .pem file in found and valid, as well my .pub key file but it still return to me a zero length in the signture...

```
$fp = fopen("/public_html/apps/chrome/nsii.pem", "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, filesize($fp));
fclose($fp);

$pkeyid = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
openssl_sign(file_get_contents("$name.zip"), $signature, $pkeyid, 'sha1');
openssl_free_key($pk);

# decode the public key

$key = base64_decode(file_get_contents('extension_public_key.pub'));

$fh = fopen("$name.crx", 'wb');
fwrite($fh, 'Cr24');             // extension file magic number
fwrite($fh, pack('V', 2));       // crx format version
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($key)));            // public key length
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($signature)));      // signature length
fwrite($fh, $key);               // public key
fwrite($fh, $signature);         // signature
fwrite($fh, file_get_contents("$name.zip")); // package contents, zipped
fclose($fh);
```

**UPDATE:**

The orignial code is as following:

```
<?php
# make a SHA1 signature using our private key
$pk = openssl_pkey_get_private(file_get_contents('/public_html/apps/chrome/nsii.pem'));
openssl_sign(file_get_contents('/public_html/apps/chrome/extGoogle.zip'), $signature, $pk, 'sha1');
openssl_free_key($pk);

# decode the public key
$key = base64_decode(file_get_contents('/public_html/apps/chrome/extension_public_key.pub'));

# .crx package format:
#
#   magic number               char(4)
#   crx format ver             byte(4)
#   pub key lenth              byte(4)
#   signature length           byte(4)
#   public key                 string
#   signature                  string
#   package contents, zipped   string
#
# see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/crx.html
#
$fh = fopen('extension.crx', 'wb');
fwrite($fh, 'Cr24');                             // extension file magic number
fwrite($fh, pack('V', 2));                       // crx format version
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($key)));            // public key length
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($signature)));      // signature length
fwrite($fh, $key);                               // public key
fwrite($fh, $signature);                         // signature
fwrite($fh, file_get_contents('/public_html/apps/chrome/extGoogle.zip')); // package contents, zipped
fclose($fh);
```

Seems is not work as well...the question is why?...
All works fine if I using CLI to compile it...

Comment: Please see the wording in your question and make yourself comfortable with the editing tools. Your code looks akward, please properly indent it as others need to read it. Also your call for help with a smiley is sometimes considered rude, because you just throw in some code and a "does not work". That's normally not enough to get some help here.

Comment: Thanks, I have update my post...my first time that I ask for help in those subjects..btw, this happen just in case I try to make a .crx from a archive .zip file, I have attached the original link with the original code..

Comment: The original code is not very failsafe. I added an answer that should give you some pointers how you can add additional checks to make it more robust.

Comment: Were you able to make it work? Very curious, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your question as-is does not leave any sign *what exactly* goes wrong.

However I can see that there is not much error checking. I suggest - as it is common for well written code - that you add some tests for return values first. Also you might need to enable error reporting and track the error log to see some of the issues.

- The chapter about [Error Handling and Logging](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php)

Let's review the code a little bit and add comments. It's not complete just some pointers. Starting with these three lines on top:

```
$fp = fopen("/public_html/apps/chrome/nsii.pem", "r");
$priv_key = fread($fp, filesize($fp));
fclose($fp);
```

You already know (at least you use it later), there is the handy function `file_get_contents`. It can replace those three lines, I add some more lines to make the code more speaking:

```
$privateKeyPemFile = "/public_html/apps/chrome/nsii.pem";
$privateKey = file_get_contents($privateKeyPemFile);
if (false === $privateKey) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException(
        sprintf("Unable to read private key file %s", $privateKeyPemFile)
    );
}
```

Next to using `file_get_contents` this is actually verifying that opening the file did successfully work. In case not, an [`UnexpectedValueException`](http://php.net/UnexpectedValueException) is thrown with an error message telling what happened. The name of the exception is not that important, you could for starters just throw an `Exception` and go along.

Throwing an exception here will actually tell the message in case this fails.

As you can see, you need to verify the return values of functions and check for the error conditions. See the PHP functions you use in the manual and look which return values are documented and what they mean. Often there are error cases, as here with [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents).

Then you are specifically concerned about the zero-length `$signature`. Let's see, for each function if we can check for return values and get some error information:

```
$keyResource = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);
```

The `openssl_get_privatekey` is actually an alias of [`openssl_pkey_get_private`](http://php.net/openssl_pkey_get_private), so this is already changed here. Also I renamed the variable name so it is more speaking, we have enough space and do not need complicated abbreviations.

Again we have a return value here, and it is `false` in case of an error. Under non-error conditions it is a key resource, so I named the return value accordingly. Let's add again the error check:

```
if (false === $keyResource) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Unable to parse and prepare private key");
}
```

So up to the next line, first unchanged:

```
openssl_sign(file_get_contents("$name.zip"), $signature, $pkeyid, 'sha1');
```

Obviously there is no error-check for the `file_get_contents` of the zip file. Instead, we need some more lines of code to have this safe:

```
$zipFile     = "$name.zip";
$zipContents = file_get_contents($zipFile);
if (false === $zipContents) { 
    throw new ... 
}
```

And as this was only for loading the data, the [`openssl_sign`](http://php.net/openssl_sign) call needs to be adopted:

```
$signatureAlgorithm = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1;
$result = openssl_sign($zipContents, $signature, $keyResource, $signatureAlgorithm);
if (!$result) {
    throw new ...
}
```

Maybe the first difference is that you've used the string `'SHA1'` while the manual told me that a constant is being used. Maybe it has the same value, I can not tell you, I used the documented constant here (It might not be that the documentation is always right, however if you have no clue what's going on, I would first of all suggest to follow the docs and then see).

Again, the return value of the function is being checked for the error condition. Assuming that your code might have failed at that function we would only know that it failed, not what went wrong.

The PHP manual shows that there is a function called [`openssl_error_string`](http://php.net/openssl_error_string) that can return (peu-a-peu) the error strings. Because it returns one after the other, you need to loop over to get all (most recent first), this can be done with a common [`for` loop](http://php.net/for):

```
for ($buffer = ''; $string = openssl_error_string(); $buffer .= $string, "\n");
```

So we could add that to the exception. Probably it's also useful to have this inside some kind of function, do what you need.

```
if (!$result) {
    $buffer = sprintf(
        "Failed to sign zip contents (%d); Openssl error(s):\n", strlen($zipContents)
    );
    for (; $string = openssl_error_string(); $buffer .= $string, "\n");
    throw new UnexpectedValueException($buffer);
}
```

So your code is a perfect example on places where to check for error-conditions and to show that different functions/libraries have different ways to signal a failure and how to obtain information about that.

If you write code in a safe way, it has all the pre- and post-condition checks, that means that you not only check return values, but you also check values before you use them. One example would be the filename of the zipfile. Check the file exists and is readable before you open it:

```
$zipFile = "$name.zip";
if (!is_readable($zipFile)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf("Zipfile is not readable %s", $zipFile));
}
$zipContents = file_get_contents($zipFile);
...
```

This is just an example, design for failure (in this case it might be a little over the top because `file_get_contents` will inform us as well that we could not read the file in case, however sometimes those pre-conditions checks are more valuable.

The code so far at once for review, moving the parameter variables to the top:

```
$privateKeyPemFile  = "/public_html/apps/chrome/nsii.pem";
$zipFile            = "$name.zip";
$signatureAlgorithm = OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1;

$privateKey = file_get_contents($privateKeyPemFile);
if (false === $privateKey) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException(
        sprintf("Unable to read private key file %s", $privateKeyPemFile)
    );
}

$keyResource = openssl_pkey_get_private($privateKey);
if (false === $keyResource) {
    $buffer = sprintf(
        "Unable to parse and prepare private key (%d) %s; Openssl error(s):\n"
        , strlen($privateKey), $privateKeyPemFile
    );
    for (; $string = openssl_error_string(); $buffer .= $string, "\n") ;
    throw new UnexpectedValueException($buffer);
}

if (!is_readable($zipFile)) {
    throw new Exception(sprintf("Zipfile is not readable %s", $zipFile));
}
$zipContents = file_get_contents($zipFile);
if (false === $zipContents) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException(
        sprintf("Failed to open zipfile %s", $zipFile)
    );
}

$result = openssl_sign($zipContents, $signature, $keyResource, $signatureAlgorithm);
if (!$result) {
    $buffer = sprintf(
        "Failed to sign zip contents (%d); Openssl error(s):\n"
        , strlen($zipContents)
    );
    for (; $string = openssl_error_string(); $buffer .= $string, "\n") ;
    throw new UnexpectedValueException($buffer);
}
```

Having the variables on top allows you to review the input parameter to the then following code upfront and give you a better overview.

Checking return values in the processing allows you to find out about problems most early.

Reading out the openssll errors will give you useful information to troubleshoot issue.

You will find almost any information for this inside the PHP manual. This answer might not solve your concrete problem but should equip you with the tools you need to better troubleshoot the issue itself and future issues you might have with code.

It only costs you some lines of code, but your code will work much better. Imagine you copy your scripts over to a new server and there things are probably different and you do not want to fly blind.

Happy debugging. As you see I only covered the first half of your code, and you should know that I did not run your code. So this example is done with the best intentions, however no guarantee it's working right away for your scenario. But I think it is visible what I wanted to demonstrate. If you apply similar checks for the rest of your code you should be able to learn what exactly is going wrong which is half of the solution.

Comment: see my code...i have update him...it's the origniall code without my changes...seems it's not working also in this version

Comment: Which errors are you getting back from openssl? Are you sure PHP can find and read `"$name.zip"``? And that are only two questions I would have looking at your code. You need to find out that. I hope my answer helps you along the way.