# Generate Chrome .crx from PHP

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, openssl, public-key-encryption

I want to generate a Chrome extension (Chrome theme) from PHP. My PHP script generates a zip file (download.zip). To convert it to a .crx package, it needs to add headers, including a public key and a signature.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5586372) answer, but you need a .pem file that generates a .pub file. I'm on a shared hosting so exec() won't work (to convert a .pem to a .pub). There is no need to have a .pem file, it only has to use it once downloading (no updating needed).

Then I saw [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php#82253) comment that explains you can generate the private and public keys. Combining the two scripts won't work (see code).

**How can I generate a keypair and use it to sign a chrome .crx package with PHP?**

This code fails (CRX_SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_INITALIZATION_FAILED):

```
// Create the keypair
$res=openssl_pkey_new();

// Get private key
openssl_pkey_export($res, $pk);

// Get public key
$key=openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$key=$key["key"];

# make a SHA1 signature using our private key
openssl_sign(file_get_contents('download.zip'), $signature, $pk, 'sha1');

# decode the public key
$key = base64_decode($key);

# .crx package format:
#
#   magic number               char(4)
#   crx format ver             byte(4)
#   pub key lenth              byte(4)
#   signature length           byte(4)
#   public key                 string
#   signature                  string
#   package contents, zipped   string
#
# see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/crx.html
#
$fh = fopen('extension.crx', 'wb');
fwrite($fh, 'Cr24');                             // extension file magic number
fwrite($fh, pack('V', 2));                       // crx format version
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($key)));            // public key length
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($signature)));      // signature length
fwrite($fh, $key);                               // public key
fwrite($fh, $signature);                         // signature
fwrite($fh, file_get_contents('download.zip')); // package contents, zipped
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were using `openssl_pkey_export` wrong and you haven't removed

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
...
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

from public key string before decoding it. I figured this out by looking at length of public key and signature. First one should be 161 and second one should be 128 bytes long ([source](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/crx.html#example)):

```
A2 00 00 00   # 162 -- length of public key in bytes
80 00 00 00   # 128 -- length of signature in bytes
```

Here is the fixed code (PHP 5.4):

```
$pk=file_get_contents('pk.pem');

$priv = openssl_pkey_get_private($pk);
$pub = openssl_pkey_get_details($priv)['key'];

# make a SHA1 signature using our private key
openssl_sign(file_get_contents('download.zip'), $signature, $priv, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1);

# geting rid of -----BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY-----
# you can probably do it better using preg_match_all / explode(PHP_EOL, $pub) etc.
$pub = trim(explode('-----',$pub)[2]);

# decode the public key
$pub = base64_decode($pub);

# .crx package format:
#
#   magic number               char(4)
#   crx format ver             byte(4)
#   pub key lenth              byte(4)
#   signature length           byte(4)
#   public key                 string
#   signature                  string
#   package contents, zipped   string
#
# see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/crx.html
#
$fh = fopen('extension.crx', 'wb');
fwrite($fh, 'Cr24');                             // extension file magic number
fwrite($fh, pack('V', 2));                       // crx format version
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($pub)));            // public key length
fwrite($fh, pack('V', strlen($signature)));      // signature length
fwrite($fh, $pub);                               // public key
fwrite($fh, $signature);                         // signature
fwrite($fh, file_get_contents('download.zip')); // package contents, zipped
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: I think `$pub = base64_decode($newPub);` must be `$pub = base64_decode($pub);`?

Comment: I can't try it out now, I will test it tomorrow. Thanks for now!

Comment: May I ask how you get/generate the pk.pem file?